# Variable undefined error in laravel blade view

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

Hey as i am passing a blade view which is having it own controller also i am including it into the view which does not have its own controller. it gives me an undefined variable error can any one help me how to it.

I have a view which does not have any controller only have Route like this `Route::get('index', function () { return view('index'); });` in this view i am passing another view which having its own controller and also having some data from an array. but after using this view inside the view i get undefined variable error.

Comment: Clearly explain question .. What you want..  ??

Comment: i am having a view which is  does not have any controller only have Route like this Route::get('index', function () {
    return view('index');
});  in this view iam passing another view which is having its own controller and also having some data from an array. but after using this view inside the view i get undefined variable error

Comment: You need pass variable to view

Comment: i am passing them

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Two steps :

1. Declare & transfer **$variable** to View from **Controller** function.

   ```
    public function index()
    {
     return view("index", [ "variable" => $variable ]);
    }
   ```
2. Indicate where transferred **$variable** from **Controller** appear in **view.blade.php**.

   ```
    {{ $variable }}
   ```

If you do not make sure, $variable is transferred or not

```
{{ isset($variable) ? $variable : '' }}
```

Answer (score 4):

If this helps anyone, I was completely ignorant to the fact that my route was not hooked with the corresponding controller function and was returning the view directly instead, thereby causing this issue. Spent a good half hour banging my head till I realized the blunder.

**Edit**

Here again to highlight another blunder. Make sure you're passing your array correctly. I was doing `['key', 'value]` instead of `['key' => 'value']` and getting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 public function indexYourViews()
  { 
    $test = "Test Views";
    $secondViews = view('second',compact('test'));

     return view('firstview',compact('secondViews'));
   }
```

and after declare `{{$secondViews}}` in your main view file(firstview).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function returnTwoViews() {
    $variable = 'foo bar';
    $innerView = view('inner.view', ['variable' => $variable]);

    return view('wrapper.view, ['innerView' => $innerView]);
}
```

This may be what you are looking for?

... inside your wrapper.view template:

```
{!! $innerView !!}
```

**EDIT**: to answer the question in the comment: In order to fetch each line you for do this inside your `$innerView` view:

```
@foreach($variable as $item)
    {{ $item }}
@endforeach
```

... and in the wrapper view it will still be `{!! $innerView !!}`

Comment: thanks it works greatly...what if i have a array of $variable. then how would i fetch the in my wrapper view.

Comment: I have edited the original response because I need to include some more code for this case.