# The output data from the database into the Template Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

Please tell me how to bring data from database to the template?

Controllers:

https://github.com/voten-co/voten/blob/master/app/Submission.php

https://github.com/voten-co/voten/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/SubmissionController.php

I try to pass {{ $submission->title }} to the template, but when loading the page Laravel gives an error "Undefined variable: submission".

I need to output the title of the article and the link to the template. How to do this?

Comment: Which line of the controller are we talking about?

Comment: 45 line........

Answer (score 0):

See the same answer question here [[Variable undefined error in laravel blade view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789211/variable-undefined-error-in-laravel-blade-view])

two steps.

Declare & transfer $variable to View from Controller function.

````
Indicate where transferred $variable from Controller appear in view.blade.php.

{{ $variable }}

if you don't make sure, $variable is transferred or not

{{ isset($variable) ? $variable : '' }}```
````

Answer (score 0):

First you need to call value in controller

```
public function index{

$data=Model::all();

return view('yourview',compact('data'));

}
```

And than write your variable  in yourview.blade.php  $data

```
{{$data->value}}
```