# How to parse single data to view laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Nah, I want to send single data from my controller to my view. But why is always "$result is undefined"?
I read the documentation but is still an error.
I just want to send single data in the view to make a condition with the blade template.

in controller

```
return view('/', ['result' => 'Unvalid']);
```

in view

```
<form action="{{route('link.check')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <center>
        <div class="form-group col-8">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="link" placeholder="Masukan web yang kalian curigai di sini">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Check !</button>
                @if ($result=='Unvalid')
                    dor
                @else
                    dorr
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</form>
```

controller

```
Route::get('/','ChekingController@index');
Route::get('/data_training','DataTrainingController@index');
Route::post('/check','ChekingController@check')->name('link.check');
```

Comment: Seems like, your `/` is rendered from another controller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable undefined error in laravel blade view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789211/variable-undefined-error-in-laravel-blade-view)

Comment: why you put / instead of view name :- in this statement
return view('/', ['result' => 'Unvalid']);

Comment: try use compact method like this :-
$result = 'Unvalid';
return view('view_name', compact('result'));

Comment: this ```/``` is will go to index. It's doesn't matter because when i run it without ```result``` is work so well.

Comment: But when i try to send an data like ```result``` in my blade template, the error is show up, i will try again to fix this problem, thank you guys you are very helpful in here ><

Answer (score 1):

why you put / instead of view name :- in this statement return view('/', ['result' => 'Unvalid']);

try use compact method like this :-

```
$result = 'Unvalid';
return view('view_name', compact('result'));
```

Comment: Wait i will try this, you make me remember about it >.<

Comment: But is doesn't work, but i will try and try to fix it, this is my controller ```Route::get('/','ChekingController@index');
Route::get('/data_training','DataTrainingController@index');


Route::post('/check','ChekingController@check')->name('link.check');```

Comment: be sure your code pass to method that hold this code :- 
$result = 'Unvalid';
return view('view_name', compact('result')); 

then if this error still exist , show screenshot from this method

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with `/`. you can declare the view name.

**change this:-**

```
return view('/', ['result' => 'Unvalid']);
```

**to:-**

```
 return view("/view_name", [ "result" => 'Unvalid']);
```